# Is there a caching DNS proxy I can add local records to?

Tags: server, software-recommendation, dns

I have a fairly standard ADSL connection. Modem/router with several computers inside. I would like to formalise some DNS entries so that when inside the network some legal DNS entries like `server.myrealdomain.com` resolves to a local IP.

<sup>**Sidebar:** the point of this is that when inside the network, devices will pick up the internal IPs and when outside the network, they'll be routed through the legal IP address and port-forwarded to the correct computer. If you think I'm approaching the problem the wrong way, tell me!</sup>

I know I can tell the router to point to my internal server for DNS, I'm just left with the choice: **Which DNS server should I use?** It has to support upstream DNS (configurable), be lightning fast (as all queries on the network will shoot through this) but be easy enough to add overrides to. What are my choices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pdnsd` is a fairly simple server that can do this. Notes:

- Enable in `/etc/default/pdnsd`
- Switch `server_ip` to `eth0` (or other), and enable `serve_aliases` in `/etc/pdnsd.conf`
- Point computers' DNS settings at this computer and win.

There is one thing causing me pain now and that's Netgear home routers being absolutely awful. Thanks to some crazy decision, you can't host your DNS server within your network. It treats it like an IP conflict for no good reason.

If you have a router that doesn't suck, you should be able to spread the internal IP of the DNS server over DHCP and you're there.